# Is there a formula behind S&W White Box classes?

Tags: osr, swords-and-wizardry

I intend to create my own classes for my current Swords & Wizardry campaign. I've read White Lies Admin Toolkit which deconstructs their own classes, but when I tried to run the same formulas to the core classes on S&W White Box I failed to see the budget for spellcasting classes, and I had the same issue with White Star.

***Is there some inner math in White Box from which everyone else creates their own systems/games?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "White Lies Admin Toolkit" but having been there at the genesis and fleshing out of S&W White Box, I can talk about the approach.

The idea was to reflect, as closely as possible, the classes of the original D&D game from 1974, using the general approach of Swords & Wizardry (1 Saving Throw, AAC, etc.). So most of the "math" is similar to what was found in OD&D. Not perfect, but a close enough analogue. For anything that I've derived from SWWB, I've kept to their example, tweaking to suite me and what I want to accomplish.

OD&D wasn't constructed in a modern thinking of algorithms, balance and budgets. It was more closely tied to what Gary & David wanted to do with their characters in their wargames and adventures. I suspect you will continue to be frustrated trying to apply a modern approach to the old school games.

Sources include the OD&D rules, the White Box rules, and various blogs from 2008-2010, including my own, and my experiences being part of the time and folks in fleshing out and blogging about S&W.

Comment: so... there is no formula? all the classes have been eye-balled?

Comment: All classes were "eye-balled" off the original OD&D rules.

If you want to look at someone who's dug into the math of OD&D, I recommend http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/ . While I can't guarantee he's gotten into the math enough for an equation you can plug in, he has done a lot of statistical work on OD&D. OD&D == S&W, so it could be of help.

Good luck!